# Loading one AJAX event causes all others to wait for it before processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a single-page application that handles business data. I'm using jQuery .ajax().

On submit of a form, we load in a request via AJAX. No problem there, the "page" is now fully loaded. When it finishes loading, I send off another AJAX request that contains a lot of information - it's a box that loads a bunch of business statistics. This can take up to 15 seconds. During this time, the browser will not process another AJAX request, which in this case is a series of navigation links that load other pages through AJAX. It will **start** the request, but it appears to be unable to load anything until the statistics-AJAX finishes its load. This is true even when I am accessing a navigation page that is merely HTML. (so it should load instantly)

I am not using async: false. A request looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'load_navigation',
    data: passed_data,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#div-to-put-result').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: How are you building `passed_data`? Is it possible that preprocessing the data is what's taking a long time?

Comment: Could it be due to URL caching?  You can try passing date with the URL.  I might be wrong.  But worth a try.

Comment: You'll need to figure out which part is taking 15 seconds.  My guess is that the creation of `passed_data` is the bottleneck.  An ajax request shouldn't hold up the page.  All of the other javascript before sending and after receiving a response will.

Comment: passed_data is just a string of data that I pass via POST. ex: action=view_stats&business_id=5. I can confirm that pulling all this information from the database takes 5-15 seconds depending on the business. It is unavoidable. I need to be able to load up a navigation item while it's doing this all in the background.

Comment: please do console.log($.now()); before ajax call ang just at the begining od success handler function. It can give as additional info.

Comment: drawing a huge chunk of text/dom/html can slow your page down.  I would start by seeing if you can eliminate a bit of it.  Maybe by json encoding your ajax response and just filling in the parameters into already rendered html.

Comment: Saram: it is most certainly this file taking so long. $now does not help in this case. I've been timing it already. John: indeed it can, but unfortunately this is just a four-column HTML table of data.

Answer (score 0):

The only idea I have is connection limitation.
Please refer to: [Max parallel http connections in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/985704/1828986).
I read that it can be limited stronger when you using low bandwidth connection, but do not have reference at this time. 
As a **test** you can put hidden `IFRAME` with get request instead of post (`$.param(passed_data)`). To get data use something like:

```
var uploadIframe = $("IFRAME");
uploadIframe.load(function() {
    var iframeBody = uploadIframe.contents().find("body");
    data = iframeBody.text();
});
```

Good luck!