# Why does an ajax request halts other script files from loading before document.ready / DOMContentLoaded event?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, asynchronous, performance-testing

I load around 50 java script files on my page. I make an `ajax` request to fetch `data` from server once the `document.ready()` is triggered. The fetching takes almost 'one second', so I thought of fetching 'data' inside one of the 20 java script file so that I can reduce that `ajax fetch time`. But to my surprise, the time taken to load the page increased by one second !!

On observing the Network tab in Chrome I found that after I made the `ajax` request to fetch the `data`, no other request to fetch the remaining java script files were sent until the `ajax` request was finished. 
Can you please tell me why the browser behaves this way? Chrome can send 6 request per origin at a given point, then why didn't it send other requests?

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET', url : 'getdata', 
    async : true, 
    success : function( res ){ 
        $.api.presInfo = res; console.log('data received'); 
    }, 
    error: function() { 
        window.location.href=ContextPath+"error.do"; 
    }   
});
```

Comment: Can you show your ajax call.

Comment: Without additional information we only can say that the request isn't async.

Comment: $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'getdata', 
            async : true,
            success : function( res ){
                $.api.presInfo = res;
                console.log('data received');
            },
            error: function() {
                window.location.href=ContextPath+"error.do";
            } 
            });

Comment: `I load around 50 java` you sure you don't mean *javascript* calls?

Comment: I mean I load them using `<script>` tag

Comment: That's a lot of JavaScript files. Maybe try to combine some of them?

Comment: @jkdev. Thats a good suggestion. But the issue here is why browser is not sending request to download other script files when an ajax call is made during page load ?

Comment: Try this answer: [Loading one AJAX event causes all others to wait for it before processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885120/loading-one-ajax-event-causes-all-others-to-wait-for-it-before-processing)